# Linux server on Wifi becomes unreachable after a few hours (but still has Internet)

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, arch-linux, nas

I have a Linux server at home running Archlinux that I use as a NAS and media center which worked fine for years over Ethernet.

I recently had to relocate the server and I cannot connect it with Ethernet anymore, so I plugged in a Wifi adapter and managed to get it to connect.

Now I have the following issue: after a while (a few hours to a day), the server becomes unreachable from other computers in the network, i.e. it looks down (ping fails, ssh fails...). However if I connect directly to the server, everything looks fine, and the server can still go on the network, download updates etc...
After a reboot, things go back to normal.

Has anyone seen this pattern before (over Wifi, after some time, host unreachable to others but able to go on the network)?

Comment: Have you verified it's not an issue with the router, as that sounds like a DHCP/DNS issue on the router, which could be caused by a number of things, however the router's system log should show what's occurring if it's the router. When you connect directly to the server when this occurs, note the IP and MAC of the adapter and cross-check that with the router's DHCP page. The reason why it corrects itself upon reboot is likely due to a new DHCP IP assigned from the router, upon which the cycle repeats.

Comment: @JW0914 the router is configured to always assign the server the same IP, and I checked during one "incident", the server reported being assigned the right IP, and connecting from my laptop to that IP still failed

Comment: Surprisingly, existing connections are unaffected by this it seems: last time I noticed I had no access from one laptop, I noticed I still had an SSH connection open to the server from another laptop, which was still alive and well.

Comment: I don't know how to do advanced network troubleshooting, but I would try tracing the connection between the server and the router and the server and another LAN endpoint; I would also review the router's system log when the issue occurs if it's accessible _(some router OEMs make the system log available without debug firmware, whereas others require flashing a debug firmware image that outputs the system log to a `localhost` port for access - if you're using opensource firmware [OpenWrt, DD-WRT, etc.] the system log is accessible from the WebUI)_